# Selecting element from drop down list using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to select element from drop down list but in html they have used `<img>` tag. How can I achieve my goal?

This is stuff from my code:

```
public void country() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Select country1 = new Select(country);
    country1.selectByVisibleText("Canada");
}
```

I am getting this error while running testNg test

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "img"

Comment: Show the HTML please. Either you got your locator wrong, or your select isn't actually a select element.

Comment: The execption states that the tag for dropdown is not select but an image. Either the element is identified wrongfully or you need to change the selection pattern. Select method works only if the tag is select. Please share the html. Will help you out.

Comment: You are right vinay they have used image tag and when i am trying to select list of item using Select class its giving me error

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned:

> ... but in html they have used `<img>` tag.

Which your error confirms. So, as per the error, you obviously cannot use `Select()`.

You did not provide enough information to give a complete answer! But think about what the user would do. First they would click on the outer element:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(country)).click();  // replace country with appropriate ID, or other locator!
```

After this the user will have to **wait** for the menu to completely appear. Same for your code!

Next, the user can click on the desired option:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Canada")).click();   // again, replace "Canada" with appropriate locator!
```

It is quite possible that the resulting menu will be long. Instead of the above `.click()` you may need to grab all the menu items based on some locator, and then iterate over all of them:

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By....);
for(WebElement item : items) {
    if(item.getText().equals("Canada"))
        item.click();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
List<WebElement> lstOptions=Country1.getoptions();
for(WebElement lstOption:lstOptions){
if(lstOption.gettext().tolowercase().equals("canada"))
lstOption.click();
}
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the issue. The base of the problem is the element the user has reference to is simply not a `select` element. So the locator is wrong or the dropdown is not a `select` but styled in a way to make it look like a `select`/dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

How to find dropdown list value.....
Use this code sure its help you!!!

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("ur xpath")).click();

 new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("EventType"))).selectByVisibleText("Birthday");
```

or

```
 new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("city"))).selectByValue("Op3");
```

Comment: The OP specified he is getting .org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "img". error. So you cannot use `Select()`.