# Selenium C# - Selecting an element from a Dropdown list gives error "Element Should have been select but was img"

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I have seen several similar questions (including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947869/selecting-element-from-drop-down-list-using-selenium-web-driver)) but none of the answers provided helped me so far resolving the issue described below.

I have the following html segment where I am trying to select a dropdown list and then click an element. But the error message shows: ***"OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been select but was img"***

[image: html segment]

Xpath I've used: //div[@class='pageTitleText']/a[@href='#']/img

C# code segment:

```
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(Driver.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='pageTitleText']/a[@href='#']/img")));
select.SelectByText("Download");
```

Comment: You can't use `SelectByText` for an image. That method is applicable for `select` meaning list boxes. Is that `img` is part of a list box? Can you simply click on the image or it's parent link?

Comment: Thank you Supputuri, followed your feedback and it's working now. Would you like to put your feedback as an answer that then I can accept as the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception 'Element should have been select but was div' C# selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025854/exception-element-should-have-been-select-but-was-div-c-sharp-selenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use SelectByText for an image. That method is applicable for select meaning list boxes. Is that img is part of a list box?

You can simply click on the image or it's parent link.